# Lightning - [sforce is not defined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ajax-toolkit

I have to create a lightning component for an action named 'Next Record' on a child object, which would check the the current records name ('Names are like Test 1, Test 2') and show us the next record of the same parent.

While doing this, I included `"soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js"` and `"soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js"` for client side query :

```
var lstCont = sforce.connection.query("select firstName, Account from Contact where Id = '"+conId+"'");
```

But, it is showing me the error :

> Uncaught Action failed: c:NextContact$controller$NextContact [sforce is not defined]

Comment: simply copy and paste JS button code and a lightning component you DO NOT make.

Comment: Have you even looked at the Lightning documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use AJAX Toolkit methods (`sforce.connection.[...]`) with Lightning Components.

If you want to query records from a Lightning Component, you'll have to create a [server-side controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_intro.htm) and [invoke it accordingly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm).

If this is your first attempt at writing a Lightning Component, I would strongly recommend starting with [this Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) first, to wrap your head around key new concepts of the Lightning Components Framework.

Comment: Or you could do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_lightning_syntax.htm